Client side printing of PDF in asp.net web application
I know that it is not possible to print using client side hardware from asp .net web application but we have a requirement where the client does not want to set the paper size of the PDF while printing using the browser print dialogue. Is there anyway to set the browser print dialogue page size according to the pdf page size as the pdf is generated by crystal report http response method and sent to the browser the pdf page size is set programmatically or anyway to print the pdf using printtoprinter methods. Any chrome extension or any other alternate solution will be also helpful
I tried to use pdfium and crystal report print to printer but neither worked. I saw a wpf service solution but it's confusing.

No. The printer dialogue of browsers is out of your control. There is no kind of uniformly defined API for this dialogue, and specifically also no API available that any website would have access to.
If you really need this, you might want the client side to install a service that does what you need locally and communicate with this service via a http-api on localhost/127.0.0.1. But keep in mind that most people probably won't install this, so this depends on your use-case.
